# Dojo : ComboBox selected and show data id

Tags: combobox, dojo

I have Dojo ComboBox with data

```js
    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore( { data: {
        identifier: "name",
        items: [
        {name:"Alabama", id:"AL"},
        {name:"Alaska", id:"AK"},
        {name:"American Samoa", id:"AS"},
        {name:"Arizona", id:"AZ"},
        {name:"Arkansas", id:"AR"},
        {name:"Armed Forces Europe", id:"AE"},
        {name:"Armed Forces Pacific", id:"AP"},
        {name:"Armed Forces the Americas", id:"AA"},
        {name:"California", id:"CA"},
        {name:"Colorado", id:"CO"},
        {name:"Connecticut", id:"CT"},
        {name:"Delaware", id:"DE"}
    ]
    }});

        var comboBox = new dijit.form.ComboBox({
        id: "stateSelect",
        name: "state",
        value: "-- Select --",
        store: store,
        searchAttr: "name"
    }, "stateSelect");
```

and I have textbox to search data id.

Then I want to selected(ComboBox) that data. 
And show the data id and value .

How can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comboBox.item is a reference to the currently selected element.

You can get the id and value of your item through :

```
var id = store.getValue(comboBox.item, "id");
var name = store.getValue(comboBox.item, "name");
```

Then you use id and name to display the values wherever you need to...

See this jsfiddle for an example : http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/RS2Z5/

Comment: Thx very much. Now I can get id and name but I don't know how to add selected like 

`<option selected="selected">Connecticut</option>`

when user submit data(id) to search in comboBox.

Comment: comboBox.item is coming as `null`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just call `comboBox.item.id` and `comboBox.item.name` in javascript....

To set the value programmically (programmically set dojo comboBox selection)..(this might not be relative to your question...just in case someone might need it)
I found that the comboBox is quite buggie when you set the selected value, if you just do:

```
comboBox.set('value', yourValue);
//such as comboBox.set('value', "Bob");
```

the box will update its display...but when you call comboBox.item it will return null....so what i did to set the selection of dojo ComboBox:
//set the display

```
comboBox.set('value', yourValue);
//set the actual selected item
comboBox.item = comboBox.store.query({myAttributesName:"myValue"})[0];
//such as comboBox.item = comboBox.store.query({name:"Bob"})[0] it will return the   Object with name = "Bob"
```

Then you will be fine by using comboBox.item.myAttribute to return whatever value you want after set selection....
Happy coding.....:p

Answer (score 0):

the id and value can be accessed via comboBox.item.id and comboBox.item.name, but in my experience the comboBox.item is null until the user clicks on the ComboBox and selects an option, once they select an option then the comboBox.item is populated with the option object that was selected.

In order to select an option and set the item you can do as Vin.X suggested or you can set it in the ComboBox initialization parameters 'item' (http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/form/ComboBox)

```
var comboBox = new dijit.form.ComboBox({
    id: "stateSelect",
    name: "state",
    store: store,
    searchAttr: "name",
    item: {name:"Alabama", id:"AL"} // or store.query({name:"Alabama"})[0]
}, "stateSelect");
```

Hopefully it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

you can find the answer in the official docs.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html#dijit-form-filteringselect

```
dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('value')
dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('displayedValue')
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```js
dijit.byId("mySelect").item.i.id
```

I don't know what "i" stands for but I got it by logging contents of `dijit.byId("mySelect").item`

Comment: I doubt if this is going to work in all cases. I think a better solution is to use the answer provided by Philippe or Vin.X.