# How do get id & text from a dojo/dijit combobox?

Tags: combobox, dojo

How do you get the id for the underlying record in a combobox with dojo? I've tried altering the following sample but all I can get is the text shown to the user (the "name" property of each array element), and NOT the state's two-letter abbreviation ("id" property).

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/ComboBox.html#id3

thanks. PS, I'm a total noob with dojo. This is my first experiment with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like @CodeCrisis said, you can get the item by using `dijit.byId('stateSelect').item`. Though I'm not really pleased with how outdated the docs are (the `dijit.byId()`command is deprecated), this is a proper 1.10 solution:

```
query("button").on('click', function() {
   console.log(comboBox.get('item')); 
});
```

This will return the selected record in the store (containing both the `id` and `name` properties in this case).

A full, working example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/zt6xggL8/

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. It's a pity about the docs because I'm currently investigating Dojo as a replacement for Ext JS (following Sencha's outrageous price hikes), and yesterday I got the impression that its combobox was pretty lame. I'll keep plodding along.

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

base on the link given 
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/ComboBox.html#id3

change this onclick function

```
onClick="alert(dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('value'))"
```

into

```
onClick="alert(dijit.byId('stateSelect').item.id)"
```

i know this is not the best answer but i hope this will help you..

check out the answer of Philippe 
[Dojo : ComboBox selected and show data id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739857/dojo-combobox-selected-and-show-data-id?rq=1)

hehehe... :) 
just passing by...

Comment: wew down vote?? im just trying to help men.... atleast tell me why so i can avoid it next time tsk tsk...

Comment: The down vote wasn't by me :-) Thanks for the post, and link to the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest but this works. Basically need to query the 'store' variable for the name that is being displayed when you just use 'value'. `[0]` denotes the first object in the store list, so if you have multiples with the same name, you'll need to use the `foreach()` function.

```
<button onClick="var namevar=dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('value');
                 alert(dijit.byId('stateSelect').get('store').query({name:namevar})[0].id);">
    Get value
</button>
```